# how to upload multiple files with drag & drop and browse with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

How can i upload multiple files via drag & drop and browse with ajax?
Code below is what i have so far and works great, but allows only 1 file to upload:

This is the html:

```
<div id="drop_file_zone" ondrop="upload_file(event)" ondragover="return false">
      <div id="drag_upload_file">
        <p>DROP FILE HERE</p>
        <p>or</p>
        <p><input class="browse" type="button" value="Browse" onclick="file_explorer();"></p>
        <input type="file" id="selectfile">
      </div>
</div>
```

Below is the javascript with ajax i use; :

```
 var fileobj;
  function upload_file(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fileobj = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
    ajax_file_upload(fileobj);
  }

  function file_explorer() {
    document.getElementById('selectfile').click();
    document.getElementById('selectfile').onchange = function() {
        fileobj = document.getElementById('selectfile').files[0];
      ajax_file_upload(fileobj);
    };
  }

  function ajax_file_upload(file_obj) {
    if(file_obj != undefined) {
        var form_data = new FormData();                  
        form_data.append('file', file_obj);
      $.ajax({

        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form_data,

        success:function(response) {
          //alert(response);
          $(".success").html(response);
          $('#selectfile').val('');
          $('.myFiles').load(document.URL +  ' .myFiles');

        }

      });
    }
  }
```

And the php for uploading:

```
$arr_file_types = ['image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg'];

if (!(in_array($_FILES['file']['type'], $arr_file_types))) {
echo "false";
return;
}
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], '../uploads/'. $_FILES['file']['name']);

echo "File uploaded successfully.<br /><br />";
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are getting only first file to upload "e.dataTransfer.files[0]". Try to change to this:

```
  function upload_file(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //here you can get all files
    for (var i=0; i< e.dataTransfer.files.length;i++){
      fileobj = e.dataTransfer.files[i];
      ajax_file_upload(fileobj);
    }
  }
```

For browsing, i guess the same logic is valid

```
function file_explorer() {
    document.getElementById('selectfile').click();
    document.getElementById('selectfile').onchange = function() {
      //here you can get all files
      for (var i=0; i< e.dataTransfer.files.length;i++){
          fileobj = document.getElementById('selectfile').files[i];
          ajax_file_upload(fileobj);
      }
    };
  }
```

If navigation do not work, you can try to reach your element by using event.target https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target

Comment: This works fine for the drag & drop!. But does not work when browsing. So how can i achieve that too?

Comment: You can use the same logic, i will update my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, i can not upload any file anymore with this code. Darag & drop works fine by the way